# When running rackup as a daemon, File.expand_path return / instead of the project folder

Tags: ruby, filesystems, rack, rackup

I'm not sure if there's something I did wrong here in some config files. When I run `rackup -D`, doing this:

```
File.expand_path(__FILE__)
```

actually returns `/file.rb`. And adding `File.dirname` somehow returns `/`. So now all my file loading code didn't work as it tries to look in the `/` directory, rather than the project directory.

This does not happen if I remove the `-D` option. It returns the full path `/home/blablabla/stuff/file.rb`

Sample code:

test.rb:

```
require 'rubygems' if RUBY_VERSION <= '1.8.7'
require 'sinatra'

get '/expdir' do
  File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
end

get '/exp' do
  File.expand_path(__FILE__)
end

get '/file' do
  __FILE__
end

get '/dirname' do
  File.dirname(__FILE__)
end

get '/dir' do
  Dir.entries(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))).to_s
end
```

config.ru:

```
require 'test.rb'

run Sinatra::Application
```

Executed it with `rackup -p 4567` and watched it return the correct values.
Executed it with `rackup -p 4567 -D` and watched it return the wrong values.

Comment: Did your process get [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)ed?

Comment: You could try some diagnostic output like: `Dir.entries('/')` and see what's there. Maybe it's the root directory, or maybe it's the root directory of your app.

Comment: Nope. It's actually the root with `/bin`, `/usr`, `/var` folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rack does indeed [change the working directory to `/` when run as a daemon](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb#L309).

In Ruby 1.8.7, `__FILE__` in a required file refers to the path used to load the file, which could be a relative path from the current working directory of the process. However this value is *not* updated if the working directory is later changed, e.g. with a call to `Dir.chdir`.

`File.expand_path` expands relative files paths relative to the working directory. So in this case `File.expand_path(__FILE__)` results in the paths relative to the root, but the value of `__FILE__` is relative to the original working directory, giving the wrong result.

In Ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3, `__FILE__` in a required file refers to the absolute path of the file, so this problem doesn’t arise.

One way to fix this in Ruby 1.8.7 is to use an absolute path when requiring your application file. Change the line `require 'test.rb'` in your `config.ru` to:

```
require File.expand_path('../test', __FILE__)
```

Now the references to `__FILE__` will be absolute, so won’t be affected by the change in working directory when daemonising.

If your application is more complicated, with more files, it might be better to set up your load path instead. For example your could put all your `.rb` files into a `lib/` directory, then in your `config.ru` add:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.expand_path '../lib', __FILE__)
```

You can then just require your files without worrying about the relative paths.

Comment: Yes. I just found out about this last night.  I reinstalled all gems, still the same problem. Then found out I was using 1.8.7. Installed 1.9.3 fixed the issue. I spent three days on this thinking something wrong with my mac :(